# Figure out if a table has a DELETE on CASCADE

Tags: mysql, database, cascading-deletes

Can I know if a database have `DELETE ON CASCADE` with a query?

Answer (score 36):

Yes. Just query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
```

Or more specifically

```
-- This query will list all constraints, their delete rule, 
-- the constraint table/column list, and the referenced table
SELECT 
  r.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
  r.DELETE_RULE, 
  r.TABLE_NAME,
  GROUP_CONCAT(k.COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', ') AS `constraint columns`,
  r.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS r
  JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k
  USING (CONSTRAINT_CATALOG, CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME)
-- using MySQL's GROUP BY clause. In other DB's more columns would need to be
-- specified!
GROUP BY r.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG,
         r.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
         r.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Read more about the [`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` table in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/referential-constraints-table.html)

Comment: If you have different schemes, you can add a WHERE r.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='schema_name' to show only the constraints of that shcheme.

Answer (score 16):

You could use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `tablename`
```

To get the entire definition of the table. This includes any foreign key constraints.